# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS won't boot

Tags: boot

Upgraded from 11.10, now my thinkpad x60 won't boot. I've tried all four different kernals on the boot menu. Each generated some different messages but all stalled at some point.

Desperately need solution.. I've gotten trusted Ubuntu too much perhaps (have been a user for a few years) so I haven't backed up my drive..

Many thanks for any suggestions..

Comment: if you now been a user for several years, tell us what the error message says! post a picture or a quote of the message.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be to try and reinstall Grub by booting into live. Boot into live, open a terminal, run "sudo fdisk -l" and find out on which partition you installed Ubuntu. It will be something like /dev/sda5. Mount that partition somewhere. You can do this by "mount /dev/sda5 /mnt" and run the following command to install/reinstall grub.

sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda (Note: It might not be sda. That depends on your hard disk's name which will be shown by "sudo fdisk -l").

Try restarting after this and hopefully it will work. :)

Or, you can boot into live and mount the partition in which you have data on and copy that data from there too.

You might want to refer to http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-using-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you so much for quick answer. Although I haven't completely digested your post, it looks doable.. I'm downloading an image and try it out.

Comment: I'm optimistic that it will work. But no promises. It won't hurt to try. That's all.

Comment: I really should have put off the upgrade.. have got a deadline on Thursday... Damn. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Make a CD of Super Grub Boot disc; it will find all the OSs and allow you to choose and boot.
Also try 'Try Ubuntu' from the Live CD, and install into it Grub Customizer. Launch that and you may be able to adjust the settings to get back to booting normally.
Super Grub disc has got me out of trouble many times.
Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I'll try out the options and report the results..